# Interaction terms of one variable with many variables

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, interaction

Suppose that I'd like to analyze the relationship between Y and A, and A moderated by B, and A moderated by C, and A moderated by D, .... and A moderated by J.

I'd then formulate my regression as follows:
Y ~ A + A:(B + ... + J)

Would this be valid mathematically and would the model be interpretable? By the looks of it, A and all the interaction terms would be heavily correlated, wouldn't it? This is essentially including only half of the main effect of the interaction (only including A as main effect and not B, ..., J).

Answer (score 6):

You should include all main effects (not just A) and all interaction (product) terms in your moderated regression model. You can reduce (non-essential) collinearity by centering the independent variables A, B, C, ..., J prior to computing the interaction (product) terms. This also often helps facilitate the interpretation of the regression coefficients, particularly when some or all of the predictor variables have no meaningful zero point. See

Cohen, J., Cohen, P., West, S. G. & Aiken, L. S. (2003). Applied multiple regression/correlation analysis for the behavioral sciences. Mahwah, NJ: Erlbaum. (Chapter 7)

Comment: Thank you! If independent variables A, ..., J are all categorical, how to center them?

Comment: With "categorical" do you mean binary (dummy variables where the two categories are coded as 0 and 1)? Binary dummy variables are not typically centered because the zero point is meaningful (0 represents a specific group).

Comment: What is meant by “centering”? I’ve only heard about centering in terms of MCMC samplers for Bayesian inference.

Comment: Centering means subtracting a constant value (often the sample mean) from each individual score.

Answer (score 1):

As has been implied above, correlations among the interacting variables create interpretation, power, and precision problems.  Contrast this with factorial designs in which all effects are orthogonal (uncorrelated) and you can fit and interpret many more interactions.  There is no hope when one of B ... J is moderately or highly correlated with A, and correlations among B ... J essential also waste parameters.  There is hope if you want to answer a more narrow scope question: do the variables that are uncorrelated with A interact with A?  And from among those variables compute the first 3 (for example) principal components and interact those with A instead of interacting the individual variables.  This will help provide evidence for the existence and magnitude of interactions before you delve back into original variable.   Oh I forgot to say (as pointed out above) that you must include all variables as main effects.

Answer (score 0):

Christian gives a good answer by giving solid advice. Only as a supplement I will give a narrow answer (that doesn't offer any advice):

- Such regression models are mathematically valid, and you *can* attempt to fit them.
- How interpretable they are depends on how comfortable you are with the mathematics and the domain knowledge.